# IOS App crashes in Release build but not in debug : IN-app purchase

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

As I said in the title, I am writing an app for iPhone which runs perfectly in debug mode but when I build it as release and install it via TestFlight, it crashes at the first page

At my first page, it loads my in-app purchase record via cloud functions instead of raw api calling.

Would you please tell me how to obtain the logs from the release version of the app or testing the app via XCode which is under release mode ?

When I catch the crash log ,  that gives the  following ;

Triggered by Thread:  0

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   bookledge                       0x0000000104425398 0x1043f0000 + 218008
1   bookledge                       0x000000010447f7b0 0x1043f0000 + 587696
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001e8130a38 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001e81317d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001e81119e4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 1008
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e868432c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e867f264 __CFRunLoopRun + 1924
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001e867e7c0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
8   GraphicsServices                0x00000001ea87f79c GSEventRunModal + 104
9   UIKitCore                       0x000000021514fc38 UIApplicationMain + 212
10  bookledge                       0x00000001043f7704 0x1043f0000 + 30468
11  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001e81428e0 start + 4
```

Extra: At the beginning, I create onBoard storyboard to put Main storyboard. Default starting point is Main. Given I have forced to turn users to redirect on OnBoard storyboard, somehow the view controller of the first page begins and calls `viewDidLoad`  and `viewWillAppear`.  When I finish scrolling to the end of the onBoard page and press the button, then ,

the first page begins and calls `viewDidLoad`  and `viewWillAppear` again.  Does this occurrence contribute to the crash log above?

Comment: Have you used fabric? Also in Xcode organiser, on select build it will show crashes of that build.

Comment: Could you please me what is fabric?

Comment: To run in release mode from Xcode just edit the Run action of the Scheme.

Comment: Fabric is third party library which show crahes in dashboard. It comes with Crashlytics framework. And using Crashlytics you can get the crash report on Fabric dashboard

Comment: Can fabric map the assembly language into readable language which points the code line of the specific modules and viewcontrollers?